# Are psychometrics used in the public sector?

Tags: measurement, mbti

If it is used, how is it used? Where is it used? Which countries are using?

Comment: Welcome Rio. This question is too broad. You might wish to visit the [help center on asking questions](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you have multiple questions, feel free to ask several. We also expect users to reveal what they have found so far. In this case there seems no attempt whatsoever to find your answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Many companies have psychometric tests to measure various cognitive and personality features.

First of all, the [intelligence quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient) (IQ) is a total score derived from several standardized tests designed to assess human intelligence. It helps filter applicants before even meeting them. IQ is the highest predictor of educational and work success.

Secondly, there are personality tests. Imagine you're looking for a lawyer. Ideally, a lawyer should be very emotionally stable and argumentative. In psychometric language, this can be measured with the [Big Five Personality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) and the desired traits would be low agreeableness and low neuroticism.

There are cooler psychometric tests that are in essence better than Big Five Personality, but they are not commonly used, because of their length or difficulty of analysis. I'm going to list my personal favorite psychometrics here:

1. [Minnesota Multiphasic Personality Inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota_Multiphasic_Personality_Inventory) (MMPI)
2. [Millon Clinical Multiaxial Inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millon_Clinical_Multiaxial_Inventory) MCMI)
3. [The Alternative DSM-5 Model for Personality Disorders](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bo_Bach/publication/293769328_The_Alternative_DSM-5_Model_for_Personality_Disorders_Validity_and_Clinical_Utility_of_the_Pathological_Personality_Traits_Criterion/links/56bb12b008ae0a6bc95616a8/The-Alternative-DSM-5-Model-for-Personality-Disorders-Validity-and-Clinical-Utility-of-the-Pathological-Personality-Traits-Criterion.pdf)

However, these psychometric tests are more useful for clinical or forensic settings rather than for Human Resources (HR). I do hope this helps.